# How to describe a vampire's red eyes

Tags: word-choice

I studied the sentence 'He has red eyes'. I know the meaning of the expression "red eyes" here.

But I wonder: if the man is an albino or vampire, his eye color is also red. I want to know an expression for describing this eye color, the way we say "Brad Pitt has beautiful blue eyes!' What can I say?

Comment: Thank you your advice:).I had a mistake when i choose the tag about my question.. I know the meaning of the expression "red eyes". I want to say about eye color such as "Brad Pitt has beautiful blue eyes!'

Comment: Yes~!! I just want to know. Expression!!

Comment: One of the meanings of _incarnadine_ is "RED esp : BLOODRED," according to Merriam-Webster. It's hard to imagine a more suitable descriptive term for vampire eye color than that.

Comment: @sumelic Of caurse!! This site is helpful!! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time, when people say "he has red eyes," they mean not the color of the iris but the redness that appears in the sides of the eye.

By default, a reader encountering the phrase "red eyes" can probably safely interpret the phrase to mean "bloodshot eyes."

Albinos are rare (respectfully), and vampires are... much more rare. To avoid ambiguity in those cases, I would use another phrase, such as "red irises," or something more elaborate like, "his eyes, the color of crimson, twinkled n the evening light."

Comment: Couldn't red eyes also refer to if someone has been crying, some one who has dry eyes, someone who has allergies, some one who as just awoken, a group of flights scheduled to depart at an early hour, or even rye whiskey?